# Aws Certificate manager me cobrara por usar un dominio de godaddy?

Tags: aws, ssl, dominio, godaddy

Tengo un dominio en godaddy que redirijo con route53 a una instancia ec2 y queria saber si me cobrara al usar un certificado SSL de aws certificate manager?

Answer (score 1):

Depende del producto que tengas contratado en GoDaddy, algunos tienen soporte para SSL de terceros y otros no. Con soporte solo se refieren a si es posible o no instalarlo y no a ofrecer ayuda.

En el siguiente link detallan el soporte según el producto.

https://cl.godaddy.com/help/godaddy-admite-ssl-de-terceros-en-sus-productos-3983